# remove LF from Datastage output to file

Tags: datastage

I am writing a file from Datastage.
The file is a TXT file where there are NO row delimimters

This means all the data is in one large long row, and not broken by records.

how do I set the outbound file sequential stage to allow for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Sequential File Stage, you can do the follow setting in Format Tab:
Record Level - To set nothing for you Record Delimiter.
Field Defaults - To set nothing for the Field Delimiter.

For example, in the Record Level setting remove all properties and add Record type = implicit will achieve what you need.

Comment: Thank you @HowMing, however, there's only three options:  null, UNIX Newline, and optional character (blank).  when I leave it blank, it says error.  How do I set this?

Comment: @arcee123, I have provide you the answer required as I have tested it on my DataStage 11.7.1.0 and if you need to have 1 line results and replace the source line with like "space", you have to use the "Record delimiter string" and input what even string you want to use as record delimiter.